# Gitlab CI/CD with JHipster and Docker registry

Tags: docker, jhipster, gitlab-ci, docker-registry

I made a JHipster application, and I want to add CI/CD with a private Gitlab runner to deploy on a private Docker registry. I get this failure:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:2.0.0:build (default-cli) on project powerfront: Invalid image reference :master-35274d52bd71e28f08a0428832001cc67e9c446d, perhaps you should check that the reference is formatted correctly according to https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/#extended-description
 [ERROR] For example, slash-separated name components cannot have uppercase letters: Invalid image reference: :master-35274d52bd71e28f08a0428832001cc67e9c446d
```

This is the relevant part of my .gitlab-ci.yml

```
# Uncomment the following line to use gitlabs container registry. You need to adapt the REGISTRY_URL in case you are not using gitlab.com
docker-push:
    stage: release
    variables:
        REGISTRY_URL: 10.1.10.58
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG-$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    dependencies:
        - maven-package
    script:
        - ./mvnw -ntp compile jib:build -Pprod -Djib.to.image=$IMAGE_TAG -Djib.to.auth.username=gitlab-ci-token  -Djib.to.auth.password=$CI_BUILD_TOKEN -Dmaven.repo.local=$MAVEN_USER_HOME
```

EDIT: There was an unconfigured variable. Now I get

```
 [ERROR] I/O error for image [10.1.10.58:5000/powerfront]:
 [ERROR]     javax.net.ssl.SSLException
 [ERROR]     Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

How do I tell the runner to accept unsecure (plaintext) connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To publish to a private (or another public) registry, your image name must start by the host name of the registry : `private.registry.io/group/image:version` so that Docker daemon knows that it doesn't push to Docker Hub (which the default) but to `private.registry.io`

Also U can use `Kaniko` to publish your image, as it doesn't require dind or privileged mode on Docker daemon.

Comment: To accept unsecured registry, you have to configure your daemon : https://docs.docker.com/registry/insecure/

Comment: I'm not familiar with jib, I'd rather user Kaniko : https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko on my CI pipelines to push images

Comment: If using jib, u may set your script to something : mvn jib -Djib.allowInsecureRegistries=true or set the flag in your pom.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is a Gitlab CI problem. but with JHipster.
What is the value for `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE`? We don't see the value in the error message.

Comment: do you try to use those gitlab variable ? CI_REGISTRY_USER and CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD ?